# Fail to create the graph. [version] field error by using galaxybase-load to load maps to Galaxybase

Tags: graph-databases

When using the import tool galaxybase-load, I encountered the following message: Failed to create the graph. [version] field error : ... , version>0 means to update the graph. , version>0 means to update the graph.
What causes this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the value of version in schema.json is not 0, the value of version must be 0 when creating the graph.